# how do I set up a navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase

I have gone through my code a couple times and I can't seem to find the answer to this. So I have a view controller and in that view controller, I have a search bar. When I type in the search bar a table view comes up. The table view is from another viewcontroller called `ResultsViewController` and the search results tableview is placed right under the search bar, which is perfect.

```
let locationSearchTable = UIStoryboard(name: "MainPage", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ResultsViewController") as! ResultsViewController
searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: locationSearchTable)
searchController?.searchResultsUpdater = locationSearchTable
```

But my problem is when I click on the cell of the table view, it segues to a `detailedViewController` and looses its navigation bar:

[image]

This is the inspector attribute for the `detailedViewController`:
[image]

I am not sure what is wrong because I am able to segue to the `detailedViewController` from other viewcontrollers:
[image]
[image]

Comment: **When I type in the search bar a table view comes up** How this tableView comes up ? Did you use presentViewController ?

Comment: @Krunal i updated it

Comment: @Surjeet no the code I used is in my question

Comment: How do your view controller appears? Push (navigating from left to right) or present (navigating from bottom to top)

Comment: @Krunal the detailedViewController? bottom to top

Comment: @Krunal I've updated with segue screenshot

Comment: Your segue needs to `Show` the next view controller, not `Show Detail`.

Comment: @NRitH I do have show

Comment: Can you show your storyboard with **all** of the view controllers associated with the question, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your details view controller has a problem with story board segue connections.

Ensure following points:

- You've navigation controller embedded in your table view list controller
- Remove segue connection from 'TableViewCell' and connect it with View controller (ViewController >> Segue >> View Controller)
- Your segue is connected as a 'push' not present

Here is sample snapshot, showing navigation bar with segue connection type:

[image]

Now, to ensure navigation controller, change your segue kind to **Push** and see:

[image]

Comment: That is what I did. I am also confused because I have segued to the detailedViewController from other multiple viewControllers and it doesn't lose its navigation bar

Comment: To ensure navigation controller, change your segue kind to push and see.

Comment: Either it will perform push navigation or your app will crash

Comment: it crashed the app

Comment: It means your tableview view controller does not have navigation controller, embedded with it. Embed navigation controller in your tableiview list

Comment: Also, one important point, Remove your segue connection from tableivew cell and connect it from View Controller

Comment: You have connected your segue using Tableview not from view controller

Comment: it still not working, I embedded the segueviewcontroller into a navigation bar and i created the segue to detailedviewcontroller from the viewcontroller and not the cell but the navigation bar is still missing

Comment: I think it might have to do with how the tableview of the segueviewcontroller is displayed on the homeviewcontroller because when i segue to the detailedViewController from other view controllers it presents from left to right not down to up like the one without the navigation bar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157014/discussion-between-krunal-and-juelizabeth).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your navigation controller bar is not hidden.

//swift 3

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
    }
```

//swift 2

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
}
```